# Why doesn't "(value) != range(0,256)" detect values outside the range 0-256?

Tags: python

```
import math
user_bin = str
while True:
    try:
        user_bin = int(input('Please enter binary number: '), 2)

    except ValueError:
        print('Please make sure your number contains digits 0-1 only.') 

    if (user_bin) != range(0,256):
        print('Please make sure your number is 8-bit')

    else: 
        print(user_bin)
```

I double checked by removing the if and else statement completely and the binary is being converted correctly, yet somehow converting 10101010 into 170 as user_bin, the result of 170 isn't considered within the range and it always prints the message 'Please make sure your number is 8-bit'. I feel like the issue is based around my range function but it could easily be other things. I doubt this is efficiently made so I'm open to any tips beyond just the solution to my question.

Comment: A number can't be *equal to* a range, that doesn't make sense. It could be *in* a range. Also note that canonical way to do this would be more like `0 <= user_bin < 256`.

Comment: ahh makes sense, thank you for the quick answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should do this:

```
if user_bin not in range(256)
```

or:

```
if 0 <= user_bin < 256
```

Also, you are setting user_bin to `str` at the start for some apparent reason.

Comment: ahh the user_bin to str was a leftover from an earlier attempted solution that I didn't know if I still needed. Originally attempted to use len() to determine the inputs length, but chose a different route.